# Proof that the cardinality of the cipher text set is greater than or equal to the cardinality of the plaintext set for a symmetric cryptosystem

Tags: symmetric

I have been working on this problem and would appreciate some help

*Consider a symmetric cryptosystem with non-empty finite sets $P, C, K$ of plaintexts, ciphertexts, and keys, respectively and with encryption functions $e_k : P \rightarrow C$ and decryption functions $d_k : C \rightarrow P$ indexed by keys $k \in  K$.*

*Show that $|C| \geqq |P|$*

---

Here is my attempt:

Since $d_k$ is the left inverse of $e_k$ by definition of a cipher

Suppose $e_k(x) = e_k(y)$ then $x = d_k(e_k(x)) = d_k(e_k(y)) = y$ for $x \in P$ and $y \in C$

meaning $e_k$ is injective $\forall k \in K$

Also, $e_k(p) = c \in C, \forall p \in P$

Suppose, for finite sets $P$ and $C$, $|P| \gt |C|$

And, since both $P$ and $C$ are non-empty, then $|C|$ is at least 1 and $|P|$ is at least 2.

Then $\exists a,b \in P$ s.t $a \neq b$ and $e_k(x) = e_k(y)$ which raises a contradiction (as it would mean $e_k$ isnt injective)

Thus, $P \not\gt C$ i.e $|P| \leqq |C|$ or $|C| \geqq |P|$

Comment: Please delete the *exact duplicate* in math stackexchange since it's been answered here. Crossposting at the same time without indication is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start of the proof, concluding $e_k$ is injective for all $k$, is fine. Only the ultra picky would add that $d_k$ is the left inverse of $e_k$ *by definition of a cipher*, and that the rest of that part considers $x$ and $y$ elements of $P$.

By my taste, the rest using proof by contradiction is on the overly complex and circular side, and less than rigorous: the "Then $\exists a,b \in P$ s.t $a \neq b$ and $e_k(x) = e_k(y)$" is not crystal clear (at least it it does not follow from a stated definition or theorem).

I would change the whole second part to: *The cardinality of the destination set of an injection is at least the cardinality of it's source set, by [definition of cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#Definition_2:_%7CA%7C_%E2%89%A4_%7CB%7C).*

Or, if [*cardinality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) is not yet formally defined in the academic context: *The size of the destination set of an injection is at least the size of it's source set, by a [counting argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Counting_argument).* The notion of counting argument is often invoked in crypto, in the context of hash collision, or proof of existence.

If we do want to make a proof by contradiction, one could invoke the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), also common in crypto, on the tune of: *$\lvert C\rvert<\lvert P\rvert$ and $e_k$ injective would contradict the pigeonhole principle*.

Comment: |P| cant be 1 since then |C| will have to be 0 (so that it is less) which doesnt satisfy the condition in the question (both P and C being non-empty).

Comment: So since |C| is AT LEAST 1, if |P|>|C| then |P| is AT LEAST 2.

Comment: @Mohamed Moustafa: right. I fixed the answer. [update: and again since the question was modified to include the missing argument].

Comment: Thanks, I added some of your remarks into my proof above. This question is from a cryptography module which is why I am trying not to use the cardinality definition or counting arguments (since we took neither in this class) and focus on properties of crypto systems and basic logic (i.e you cant injectively map a larger number of elements to a smaller number of elements).

Comment: I understand. You are trying to workaround the lack of definition of set size / cardinality. I don't see how to avoid some level of handwaving or intuitive notion at the point "Then $\exists a,b \in P$ s.t $a \neq b$ and $e_k(x) = e_k(y)$", which doesn't invoke any definition or theorem.  That's why I would skip the whole attempt of proof by contradiction, an move on.

Comment: If you want to map all values in P to some value in C (function), and each value of C can have a single value of P at most mapped to it (injectivity), then it is impossible to do so if there are more values in P than in C. Let us say we map |C| P values. To map the |C|+1 value of P, we will have to map it to some value of C that already has some other value of P mapped to it. Meaning it will no longer be injective.

Comment: @Mohamed Moustafa: right. You have just stated the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), as I do in the last paragraph of my answer. Which admittedly I added only late ;-)

Comment: just saw the last part, sorry didnt notice before